# What is the dry time where can you pressure test a DWV system after glueing?

Tags: drain-waste-vent, pressure

I just pressure tested my system and found a leak in some old connections. So I removed them and added some piping. The dry time for use is 2 hours. Is it the same for pressure testing to 5psi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manufacturer of the solvent should have a specification on the container but if not specific, I'd go by the "dry time for use".

Keep in mind that a DWV pipe is unlikely to experience 5 psi under normal use so you don't want to test too soon and risk blowing your joints apart.